# Lookup Partial String To Return Data From Corresponding Columns and Rows (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, search, lookup

I have a client/job database for which I would like to be able to do partial and full searches. This database includes at least 19 different pieces of data, e.g. Company Name, Company Address, Point-Of-Contact, job start and end date, job revenue etc..

I have a single search field, where I can enter different column inputs and search for the relevant client. For example, If I key in Client Name, it will return all jobs with that client. If I search 201X, it will return all jobs done in 201X. This returned data is populated as a list below my search box.

My current problem is I am unable to do partial searches. E.g. I must type in 'General Electric', as opposed to just 'Electric'. The VBA code I've used is provided below. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
Option Compare Text 
Sub SearchClientRecord()

Dim Search As String 
Dim Finalrow As Integer 
Dim SearchFinalRow As Integer 
Dim i As Integer 
Dim scs As Worksheet 
Dim scd As Worksheet

Set scs = Sheets("Client Search") 
Set scd = Sheets("Client Database")

scs.Range("C19:S1018").ClearContents

Search = scs.Range("C12") 
Finalrow = scd.Range("D100000").End(xlUp).Row 
SearchFinalRow = scs.Range("D100000").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 3 To 19 
For i = 19 To Finalrow

If scd.Cells(i, j) Like Search Then 
scd.Range(scd.Cells(i, 3), scd.Cells(i, 19)).Copy
scs.Range("C100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 
End If 
Next i 
Next j 
scs.Range("C19:S1018").Select
    scs.Range("$C$18:$S$1009").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 _ , 7), Header:=xlYes

Call Border Columns("C:S").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

End Sub 
Sub AddJobDetail() 
JobDetailForm.Show 
End Sub
```

Comment: You need wildcards with your `Like`: `If scd.Cells(i, j) Like "*" & Search & "*" Then`

Answer (score 2):

Use the Instr function to find one string within another - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx

e.g. replace

```
If scd.Cells(i, j) Like Search Then
```

with

```
if Instr(scd.Cells(i,j), Search) > -1 then
```

But of course be careful typing 'Electric' if you have 'General Electric' and 'Electric Motors' :)